# Meteor default http auth

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, axios, basic-authentication

I have a meteor app which makes HTTP calls to some server with basic auth.

Now I want to use a modifier (axios provides interceptors which can modify the requests before sending them) such that on the basis of url, I should be able to add authorization headers.

Eg:

```
HTTP www.a.com/route1
HTTP www.b.com/route1
HTTP www.a.com/route2
```

What I want to accomplish is, whenever a request is made to `www.a.com`, I need to add headers.

I cannot do it manually for each request currently being sent as there are hundereds of requests being sent from different modules of the app.

Already thought of writing a wrapper around meteor's `HTTP` but any better option like interceptors?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this, [Documentation of Meteor's HTTP API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html)? This package allows you to specify headers and such settings.

Comment: The document specifies how to add headers for requests. What I want is insert an authorization header in every request. 
So instead of specifying the header with each HTTP.call, I would write an interceptor which would insert the required headers before the actual request is made.